# why I was not able to send _/\_ on chat

Tags: support

I am trying to send `_/\_` on chat.But when I send `\`is missing,I tried different combinations.

I have certain idea that chat edit also same as https://askubuntu.com/editing-help.

But when I type  `_/\ _`  or `_ /\ _` like this,`\` not missing.

test [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24559409#24559409) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24559360#24559360)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underscore is a markdown *formatting* directive for emphasis, equivalent to an asterisk. To markdown processing a character in a meaningful way, you can escape it with a backslash, so `\_` is being read as "escape this underscore".

To stop it being escaped, escape the escape: `\\_`

You might to still escape the underscore, so `\\\_` would probably be safest.

Comment: thanks =)@Oli,just similar to escape sequences in java ?

Comment: Similar to escape sequences in most input schemes.

Comment: thanks =)..@Oli